# Trying to print the value of an integer and the code never returns

Tags: haskell, ghci

I tried this code:

```
c = 42

c

c = c + 1

c
```

and it never returns from the last line. What did I do?

[image]

Comment: Because you defined `c` in terms of itself, so `c = ((((...c)+1)+1)+1)+1`.

Comment: In order to calculate `c = c + 1`, it first needs to calculate `c`, and for that it first needs to calculate `c + 1`...

Comment: In C/C++/Fortran/Java/Python ..., the instruction `c=c+1` means `NewValueOfC = OldValueOfC + 1` ; but it is not so in Haskell. Haskell values are *immutable*. So `c=c+1` is just a bottomless recursive definition of c.

Comment: I guess you wanted to update `c` but what you really did was more like this: `int C() { return C() + 1; }; C();`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
Prelude> let s = "hello " ++ s
Prelude> s
"hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello ...
```

What you tried did essentially the same thing, except that integer addition is strict: there is no way to evaluate even part of `c` without already having computed `c` completely, which requires first knowing `c` completely, which requi...

By contrast, the first characters of `"hello " ++ s` can be evaluated without ever touching `s`, and then again the first characters of `s` can be touched without going further in the recursion, and so on – you only need a finite depth of recursion to obtain a given number of characters.